# Sony Bravia Android TV - How to enable/retrieve adb logcat logs

Tags: android, sony, android-tv

First, have any of you guys experienced that once in a while when starting the Sony Bravia Android TV(KD-55X8505C), there is no picture, You need to reboot the tv to get the picture back?

Secondly, does anyone know how to troubleshoot this i.e. enable/retrieve adb logcat logs from the tv?

Yes, I have the newest Android firmware version and also tried to do a factory reset with no success.

Answer (score 1):

To get logs from the TV you need to use ADB over TCP/IP.

1. Enable Developer options: Press Home and select Settings. In the TV row, select About. Scroll down to and click on Build several times until a dialog appears with the message "You are now a developer" appears.
2. Enable Debugging: Press Home and go back into the Settings menu. In the System Preferences row, select Developer options, select Debugging, select ADB Debugging, select On.
3. Find the TV IP address: Press Home and select Network Settings.
4. Make sure your TV and your computer are connected to the same local network.
5. On your computer, open a terminal and type: `adb connect <IP address of your TV>`
6. In the Allow debugging? dialog, select Always allow from this computer and select OK.
7. You can verify the connection is established by typing: `adb devices`
8. To get a log, type: `adb logcat`